# Find the ratio of recursive integrals

Tags: ratio

Given $ I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n\theta d\theta $, the recursive formula can be found as

$$ I_n = \frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2} $$

The lecture notes later state that

$$ \frac{I_{2n-1}}{I_{2n+1}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2n} $$

When I try to calculate the ratio based on the recursive formula, I get other terms that cannot be cancelled, e.g.:

$$ \frac{I_{2n-1}}{I_{2n+1}} = \frac{\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}I_{2n-3}}{\frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{2n-1}} 
= \frac{(n-2)(2n+1)I_{2n-5}}{n(2n-3)I_{2n-3}} $$

Please, could you help to get the ratio?

Comment: Just substitute n by 2n+1 in the first equation and do simple manipulation.

Comment: Put $m=2n+1$ so that $m-2= 2n-1$ applies the your formula for $I_m$ and $I_{m-2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial Hint: By the first equation of
$$
I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}
$$
you know that plugging in $n=2n-3$ you can get that
$$
I_{2n-3} = \frac{2n-4}{2n-3}I_{2n-5}.
$$
Try plugging this in and seeing if that gets you anywhere

---

Even easier version I realized after the fact: When you first do
$$
\frac{I_{2n-1}}{I_{2n+1}}
$$

just plug in the version of
$$
I_{2n+1} = \frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{2n-1}
$$
only, instead of substituting for both $I_{2n-1}$ *and* $I_{2n+1}$